# How can I get the text from the data-label to appear above the progress bar rather than inside of it?

Tags: html, css

I would like this bar to have the text appear above it. I have been searching for a couple hours, decided to just leave it and then i thought why not ask here, if anyone could give me some insight on this that would be great, thanks!

```css
.exp_bar_container{
  width:100%;
  top: 12em;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;

}


.ExpBar {
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  position: relative;
  font-weight:bold;
  float: left;

}
.ExpBar:before {
  content: attr(data-label);
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.ExpBar .value {
  background-color: #323334;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}


.ExpBar::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #dcdcdc;
}

.ExpBar::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #630862;
}

.ExpBar::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #dcdcdc;
}
```

```html
    <div class="exp_bar_container">
      <progress id="ExpBarId" class="ExpBar" data-label='20/20' value="1" max="100">

      </progress>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `top: -1em;` to `.ExpBar:before`:

```css
.exp_bar_container{
  width:100%;
  top: 12em;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;

}


.ExpBar {
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  position: relative;
  font-weight:bold;
  float: left;

}
.ExpBar:before {
  content: attr(data-label);
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -1em; /* added */
}
.ExpBar .value {
  background-color: #323334;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}


.ExpBar::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #dcdcdc;
}

.ExpBar::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #630862;
}

.ExpBar::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #dcdcdc;
}
```

```html
<div class="exp_bar_container">
      <progress id="ExpBarId" class="ExpBar" data-label='20/20' value="1" max="100">

      </progress>
    </div>
```